# How to create clickable icons on the Custom Title Bar

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, custom-titlebar, android-titlebar

I want to create the click effect on the following type of custom title Bar.

[image]

There are three functions in here:Home,Title and Search, clicking either of it should perform the further function.

I was following this

http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/android-dynamic-and-custom-title-bars/

But i want the effect which i have posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are talking about is called [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). This is specially designed for Android Tablets. But developers have made Action Bar available for Android Mobile Phones too.

Have a look at [Action Bar written by johannilsson](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar). You can simply download this library project and customize according to your need and then integrate this library to your project.

Other Action Bar examples :

[Xoriant Action Bar](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-ui-design-pattern-action-bar.html) --

Note : THIS IS THE SAME THING THAT YOU WANT as you want to have Home, Search and Title on it.

[Thiranjith blogspot](http://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/actionbar-design-pattern-example-for-android/)

Comment: this action bar can be used on API level 11.will this work for a application which i am developing using API level 2.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this..

1) First create two layouts like `main & custom_title`

2) You must include the drawables which type like you've posted here. And, use this code.

main.xml  - Just designed whatever you want.

custom_title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="35dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:background="#323331">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="hello"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
}
public void hello(View view)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi, this is test.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Change this code to your needs. Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for replying..but i have tried this but not getting the desired output I am getting the effect as shown in the link i referred..i want to create UI like i the image i shared..